# OpenDKIM gets installed without RSA-SHA256 support

Tags: email, email-server, opendkim

I compiled opendkim from source with the following commands:

```
mkdir /opt/opendkim
cd /opt/opendkim
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/opendkim/files/opendkim-2.10.3.tar.gz
tar -xzvf opendkim-2.10.3.tar.gz
cd opendkim-2.10.3
./configure --with-openssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-sql-backend=mysql --with-odbx
make
make install
```

In the configure output, I can find these lines. I assume it has found openssl correctly?

```
checking for OpenSSL includes... no
checking for OpenSSL library and includes... /usr/bin/openssl
```

OpenSSL is installed in version OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023)

opendkim -V gives me the following output:

```
opendkim: OpenDKIM Filter v2.10.3
    Compiled with OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
    SMFI_VERSION 0x1000001
    libmilter version 1.0.1
    Supported signing algorithms:
        rsa-sha1
    Supported canonicalization algorithms:
        relaxed
        simple
    Active code options:
        USE_ODBX
    libopendkim 2.10.3:
```

trying to start opendkim results in

```
opendkim[9049]: verifier mode operating without rsa-sha256 support; terminating
```

Comment: Why do you build from source?

Comment: Because the Amazon Linux 2023 image does not provide an installation via dnf, or does it?

Comment: Opendkim is broken and appears to be no longer supported. That version, 2.10.3, is from 8 years ago. Opensuse has patches for it, but even with them, it still does not work.

Comment: @Bib do you know an alternative?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't. You could try grabbing the patches and have a go yourself at making it work.

Comment: @daydr3amer https://pypi.org/project/dkimpy/